# Delete folders which contains special chars in Python

Tags: python, directory, special-characters, python-2.x

I have some folders which names contains special chars.
I tried to remove them like this:

```
shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(mypath,"Input"))
```

and I get an error:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:
>   ...\library elements ???? ?????

and my Folder name is :

> library elements 階段要素 Элементы

How can I delete this folder?

Thanks David

Comment: What os are you doing this on?

Comment: Windows 10 but I need Mac OS too

Comment: Works fine for me on linux, have you encountered the same issue on mac?

Comment: I didn't try yet. First I want to solve on Windows .

Comment: This is a windows specific issue http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2030845/file-directory-volume-label-syntax-incorrect.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on Python 2.x, this appears to be a [known bug in Python 2.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue24672). It's likely a problem with locale handling when using the ANSI APIs on Windows (Unicode and locale handling was much weaker in the 2.x line).

Assuming you can't switch to Python 3.x, try passing the path as a `unicode` path, rather than `str`, so it exercises the Windows Unicode APIs (that will handle the non-ASCII names correctly). Since your base path appears to be an ASCII `str`, this can be done by changing:

```
shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(mypath,"Input"))
```

to:

```
shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(mypath,"Input").decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Yes I use Python 2.7.10, but this solution work perfectly. Thanks!